# Bound on integral of rational functions over [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, inequalities

I have a question about integrals of rational functions over $[0,1]$. Suppose $f(x),g(x)$ are two nonzero polynomials with non-negative (*integer*, in fact) coefficients. Under what *non-trivial* conditions on $f$ and $g$ can we ensure that
$$\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx\leq \frac{f(1)}{g(1)}?$$
(Of course, if the function $f(x)/g(x)$ is increasing on [0,1], then the inequality holds.)
Are there closely related inequalities in the literature? I am looking for interesting conditions that appear in the literature.